# Pass inputs from a form to empty divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm passing data in a form from page1, to page2.

On page1

```
<form action="page2.html" method="get" id="newMember">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="memberName">
  <input name="age" type="number" id="memberAge">
  <input name="binary" type="radio" id="memberBinary">

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then on page2, the url will look like the following:

```
..page2.html?name=bob&age=21&binary=yes
```

So what I would like to do, is fill in the  empty divs using jQuery, with corresponding data points from the url.

On page2, I have the following empty divs

```
<div id="name"> </div>
<div id="age"> </div> 
<div id="binary"> </div>
```

I'm not sure how to grab the data points in the url and pass them to the empty divs, using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by accessing window.location.search, then sanitizing it. Looping through each item within the pair, you can then write the text based on the id. This one-liner will do this all, but must be run when the DOM is fully loaded.

If you are using jQuery, then put this code in `$(document).ready()`, as well, update the textContent code to use the jQuery variant as it's supported across more browsers (I think).

Here is the pseudo-code:

1. Remove leading question mark
2. Split the string into an array of key value pairs
3. With each pair, find the DOM element with the ID equal
   to the key and set its text content to the value.

Below is the pure JavaScript version:

```
window.location.search
    .replace(/^\?/, '')
    .split('&')
    .map(function(pair) {
        var keyValue = pair.split('=');
        var element = document.getElementById(keyValue[0])
        if (element) element.textContent = keyValue[1];
});
```

jQuery Variant:

```
window.location.search
    .replace(/^\?/, '')
    .split('&')
    .map(function(pair) {
        var keyValue = pair.split('=');
        var element = $('#' + keyValue[0])
        if (element) element.text( keyValue[1] );
});
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from javascript:

```
function getQueryStringByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And then you can use this function as:

```
var name = getQueryStringByName('name');
```

and then you can put this name into the innerHTML of your div with id = 'name'

Hope this helps.

Comment: This functionality should be on the page2 where you actually want to get the query strings.